# onclick event on anchor tag running partial function

Tags: javascript

Belwo is my function which i want to execute on click event of anchor tag. I have tried two methods but none of them working completely fine.

1st way:

```
<a href="/" id="btn_shopping" onClick="logContinueShopping();">Continue Shopping</a>
```

In this way my function is not working unless i put event.PreventDefault() within my function. But as i put event.PreventDefault() in my logContinueShopping() function, the function works fine but anchor tag is not working as obvious.

2nd way:

```
<a href="#" id="btn_shopping" onClick="logContinueShopping(); document.location='/'">Continue Shopping</a>
```

In this way, my function is running till ajax request but the success function is not executing i.e it is not setting the cookie and redirection the page to '/'.

```
 function logContinueShopping(){
            var action = 'continue_shopping';
            // Check if the activity is already logged
            var checkCookie = getCookie('continue_shopping');
            if(checkCookie == ''){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:  '/ajaxCall/user-activity-ajax.php',
                    data: {
                        action:action,
                        url:url
                    },
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        document.cookie = "continue_shopping  = " + action + "; path=/";
                    }
                });
            }
```

I would request to please not to provide jQuery solution as i m forced to use javascript here.

Thanks alot.
            }

Comment: Then why are you using jQuery?

Comment: For Ajax Only. @billyonecan

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use jQuery but you are allowed to use its `$.ajax` functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about setting the `document.location` in your `success` handler? :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ajaxCall/user-activity-ajax.php',
    data: {
        action: action,
        url: url
    },
    success: function (response) {
        document.cookie = "continue_shopping  = " + action + "; path=/";
        document.location = '/';
    }
});
```

Comment: this is an option but what if something happend wrong with my update function... Also this anchor tag is on multiple pages how ever i want to use the function only on 1 page. On rest of the pages my updatefunction wont bhi working so i am putting the document.location out of the ajax call

Comment: This, and also don't make it an anchor tag, because we don't want it to behave like one anyway. Make it a button or a span or whatever, and style it like an <a> if you want.

Comment: @Chris I've just got a task to log activity on click . If that would be in my hand i would never make it anchor :(

Comment: Oh, that's the worst. My sympathies.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
 change href="javascript:void(0)"

and user window.location="/" on success of the ajax call to redirect.

Comment: Sir, I have mentioned the reason in above answer for this (

Comment: By your code i am having the same problem.. The code works fine till my ajax request. It works fine on the server end as well but it is not coming in success block

Comment: please see my below answer. This is working fine ..I guess it is holding the window.location unless i received response from server.

Answer (score 0):

I have placed `async: false` and used the function in below way

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="btn_shopping" onClick="logContinueShopping(); window.location='/'">Continue Shopping</a>
```

Thanks for contribution.